# If an all maps f from an arbitrary manifold Y to manifold X are homotopic, then X is contractible

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

Feeling silly that I'm not getting this proof.

I have the proof that if a manifold X is contractible then all maps from an arbitrary manifold $Y$ into $X$ are homotopic, but no its converse. any hints would be appreciated.

thanks!

Edit: My confusion was the word "arbitrary", I falsely interpreted it as "some  fixed" manifold Y given the manifold X. English is my second language so thanks for bearing with me and my silly question.

Thank you

Comment: Is $X$ a manifold?

Comment: Yes, I'm so sorry, edited.

Comment: Consider the identity map $X$ to $X$.

Comment: I'm confused, the assumption is that there exists an manifold with this property right? How do I know it's X?

Comment: *Arbitrary* means *any*, so in particular $X$

Comment: Ok....so I have been confused over something silly. I see why it's true now, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The devil is in the details and in this case it is in the word *arbitrary*. To conclude that $X$ is contractible, we need to know that *for any manifold* $Y$ it holds that any two maps $f, g\colon Y\to X$ are homotopic. Indeed, if this is the case, we can simply take $Y=X$ and conclude that any map $f\colon X\to X$ is homotopic to the identity.

The formulation of your question had confused me as well. Note, however, that if $Y=\{a\}$ is a one-point manifold then all maps $f,g\colon Y\to X$ are automatically homotopic. This shows that one needs to require something more.

Comment: Yeah I was really confused by myself from falsely interpreting the converse. I thought the assumption was regarding maps from some particular manifold Y.

Comment: What about the converse any ideas please @Ecotistician

Comment: @Devendra Singh Rana See my edit, I too incorrectly interpret the word "arbitrary", here it doesn't mean "some fixed", it means "any". So to show the converse you are allowed to choose a particular Y (since the assumption is the statement is true for ALL Y). So pick Y = X, and f be the identity, and g be any constant map from X to a point on X.

Comment: @ Devendra Singh Rana The converse can't be true if we interpret "arbitrary" as "some fixed"; the counter example is since if you choose X to be S^2, Y to be a one point space, then since X is path connected any maps from Y are homotopic (the homotopies are just paths), but clearly X isn't contractible.

Comment: Yaa i got this one easily, I am actually asking about the first part of the question @Ecotistician

Comment: @ Devendra Singh Rana The other part is just as easy, assuming X is contractible, there exists a point p in X and a homotopy H : X x I -> X such that H(x,0) = id , H(x,1) = p. Let f be any map from Y to X, consider the homotopy obtained by post-composing the map (y, t) -> (f(y), t) with H. More explicitly, consider the map from Y x I -> X defined by, (y, t) ->  H(f(y), t)