# How do I prove that all smooth manifolds being homotopic implies contractible?

Tags: differential-topology, homotopy-theory, stable-homotopy-theory

Let $X$ and $Y$ be smooth manifolds. If all smooth maps from $Y$ to $X$ are homotopic, then show that the identity map on $X$ is homotopic to some constant map(i.e that $X$ is contractible).

I have already proved the converse of this. The strategy there was to show that any arbitrary smooth map from $Y$ to $X$ are homotopic to the constant map, hence they are all homotopic to each other as homotopy is an equivalence relation. But, what strategy is to be used to prove the converse? Any hints/suggestions would be appreciated?

Comment: Maybe you are asking: If all smooth maps from all smooth manifolds Y to the given X are null homotopic then X is contractible? This would be true. Regardless, you should describe what did you try to solve the problem

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2787176/if-an-all-maps-f-from-an-arbitrary-manifold-y-to-manifold-x-are-homotopic-then?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

This is not true, take $Y$ to be a point, all maps $Y\rightarrow X$ are homotopic if $X$ is (path) connected, but $X$ is not necessarily contractible.